# How to Separate Between Mouse Move and Mouse Wheel Events?

Tags: javascript

```
var timer;
var stoppedElement=document.getElementById("stopped");   // store element for faster access

function mouseStopped(){                                 // the actual function that is called
    stoppedElement.innerHTML="Mouse stopped";
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
    stoppedElement.innerHTML="Mouse moving";
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(mouseStopped,300);
});
```

This fiddle detect the mouse move but when moving the mouse wheel it said that mouse is moving, can we separate between move and wheel events ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529807/mousemove-event-is-triggered-onscroll-even-when-mouse-was-not-moved-on-chrome

Comment: well when I move mouse wheel(scroll) it doesn't say 'mouse moving'. maybe your mouse is broken?

Comment: @jackjop How about chrome? See the link.

Comment: Yes this is in chrome only, in firefox it just say "mouse moving" when move not when wheeling

Comment: I tested  this in chrome actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to scroll events, Webkit browsers fire mousemove events, since the cursor can be in a different position after the scrolling.

The solution is to manually check, whether the position changed, or not:

```js
var timer;
var stoppedElement=document.getElementById("stopped");   // store element for faster access

function mouseStopped(){                                 // the actual function that is called
    stoppedElement.innerHTML="Mouse stopped";
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    if ((window.lastX !== e.clientX && window.lastX !== undefined)
        || (window.lastY !== e.clientY && window.lastY !== undefined)) {
        stoppedElement.innerHTML="Mouse moving";
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer=setTimeout(mouseStopped,300);
    }   
    window.lastX = e.clientX
    window.lastY = e.clientY
})
```

```html
<div id="stopped"></div>
```